# Does an FAD:FADH2 ratio exist in the cytoplasm? (similar to NAD+:NADH ratio?)

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, metabolism, energy-metabolism

I have learned about a lot of enzymes/proteins which are covalently bound to FAD, and use this as an oxidising agent. In vivo, FAD is (almost) always protein bound (very low concentrations of free FMN/FAD [[source]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25488801)). Would an "*FAD:FADH2* ratio" make sense (if it isn't free)? I know that the *NAD+:NADH* ratios in the mitochondria and in the cytoplasm are important, same for *NADP+:NADPH* (e.g. low *NADP+:NADPH* ratio in cytoplasm makes the reducing environment for fatty acid synthesis). Is it the same for FAD?